# How do I extract genomic data from databases such as GEO or TCGA by using Python?

Tags: python

I am reletavely new to python and been trying to learn python by hands-on approach. Right now I have to extract genomic data of breast cancer via genomic databases such as TCGA, GEO etc. to write a review article on cancer metastasis. I have been having troubles and issues with writing the code. If any coder could help me out of it. It would mean the world to me. Thanks!

I haven't tried anything yet.

Comment: You might want to post this under bioinformatics.stackexchange.com as well, as knowledge of the relevant databases and if/what kind of API they have is more relevant than the actual programming language you use to access them